# How to create and access a static object

Tags: c++, static, singleton

This is the error I'm getting:

```
'global_grid' was not declared in this scope
```

This line in class `Notator` (defined below) is causing the error:
`int option = global_grid.GetOption();`.

---

The `Director` is coordinating different modules that work with the grid. I need one grid to be available to all classes. I don't want it to be a singleton, because there could conceivably be more than one grid. I don't want it to belong to the `Director` class, because that doesn't make sense to me conceptually. The `Director` just directs traffic.

I thought that `global_grid` (declared below) would be visible everywhere. I guess I'm not understanding `static`, or maybe how to access the object.

Without the statement that caused the error, the project compiles. What am I missing?

```
class SoundFile // This module has a grid that is needed by the other modules
{
    public:
        int GetOption(){ return 0; }
};

class Director //  Coordinates communication between modules
{
  public:   
      SoundFile& CreateGrid()
      {
        static SoundFile grid; // All modules need access to this grid.
        return grid;
      }
      
      void SetUp() // I want to call this when the app starts, to 
                       //create a global grid.
      {
        SoundFile& global_grid = CreateGrid(); // Would this create a static object? 
      }
};

class Notator // One of the modules that needs access to the grid
{
    public:
        void Work() 
        {   
           int option = global_grid.GetOption(); // Causes the error
        }
};
```

Comment: plese create a [mre]

Comment: Ok, let me read the info at the link

Comment: `global_grid` is a local identifier in `Director::SetUp`

Comment: The error message refers to `global_grid`. Why do you think `global_grid` is static? The only declaration you have with the `static` keyword is for `grid`.

Comment: Actually, this whole business of "static" is irrelevant to your error. ("Static" does not mean "global".) Read the error message again: "declared in this scope". Why do you believe that `global_grid` (declared locally within `Director::SetUp()`) is declared in the scope where the error occurs?

Comment: @JaMIT I understand what you mean. I figured SoundFile& global_grid = CreateGrid(); made global_grid static because CreateGrid() seems to create a static object and return it.

Comment: @JaMIT I thought static meant "not attached to a class." I've read various wordings of what it is, but I'm not clear on what it actually means. What I want is an object that will be available everywhere. How can I do that without doing a singleton?

Comment: @jana You are probably thinking of [static members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) of a class, which are not attached to a specific **object** (but are still part of the class). What you have in your code is a [static local variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables), which has nothing inherently to do with classes. (Both do use the `static` keyword, which some might find confusing. The meaning of the `static` keyword is different in these two cases.)

Comment: @JaMIT. Ok, I'll look it up again and clarify it for myself. So then is there any way to create a globally available object that isn't in a class?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be inclined to create a global variable, which typically is poor style, indicative of a need for design review. I think this is the case with your code. However, your code has some elements that suggest that parts of your design are on the right track. I'll provide a push in that direction, but please understand that this is not intended as final code; I would expect further adjustments as you review and improve your design.

One good aspect is that you have your intended "global" grid as part of your `Director` class. This is better than having a global variable, if there is a logical reason for the global grid to be strongly associated with the `Director` class. Perhaps a different class would be a more logical choice; that would be something for you to review once you see what can be done. It might even be reasonable to make the "global grid" part of your `SoundFile` class. The point is to have access to the global grid be under some suitable name (class or namespace), rather than be at global scope.

You actually have most of what you describe you want. Your `CreateGrid()` function creates a `SoundFile` object, namely the `grid` [static local variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables), the first time it is called, then subsequent calls return a reference to the same object as the previous call. (The name is a bit odd since no calls but the first create a grid.) This could be your global grid, except a `Director` object is needed to invoke this function.

Declaring this function to be a [static member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) of `Director` would get rid of the need for a `Director` object when calling `CreateGrid()`. Furthermore, this would be a logical thing to do since that function does not make use of the object through which it is called (a.k.a. `*this` inside the function).

```
class Director
{
  public:   
      static SoundFile& CreateGrid()  // <-- add the `static` keyword here
      {
        static SoundFile grid;        // <-- (and keep the `static` keyword here)
        return grid;
      }
};
```

There was no need to try to assign the return value of this function to a "global" variable. The function call can be used wherever you were going to use the variable. For example:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << Director::CreateGrid().GetOption() << '\n';
}
```

This approach shares some similarities with the singleton design pattern, but this approach does not prohibit other `SoundFile` objects from existing. There is merely one of these objects that has a special designation and a lifetime that lasts as long as the program.

---

Note that you could instead make `grid` be a static data member of the `Director` class. However, the member function approach has two advantages that you might benefit from in the long run. First, a member function improves encapsulation since callers need not know exactly how the `SoundFile` object is obtained. You could change the implementation without requiring code changes throughout your program. Second, using a member function helps avoid the phenomenon called "[static initialization order fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof)".

Comment: I appreciate the code examples. No question, the real problem is my design. I was going to make the function a static member of ```Director```. Then I reviewed some design patterns, and the mediator pattern turns out to be appropriate. The ```Director``` manages a group of modules, and often those modules need the grid. So the grid is a member of ```Director```. The ```Director``` takes user input then calls the appropriate module method, passing the grid to it. And the module notifies the ```Director``` on completion.